Error invalid attempt to set a new value for property "recordId" that does not has a setter decorated with @api
I am implementing LWC URL Addressable as the documentation. However, I am getting the following error messages in the browser's devtools console:

"Invalid attempt to set a new value for property 'recordId' that does
not has a setter decorated with @api"


"Invalid @api recordId field. Found a duplicate acessor with the same
name."

"recordId" is only used to call an Omnistudio integration procedure and for the URL Addressable. What could be happening?
MyComponent.js
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation'; 
import { getNamespaceDotNotation } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptInternalUtils";
import { OmniscriptActionCommonUtil } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptActionUtils"; 
import { OmniscriptBaseMixin } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptBaseMixin";
import { setTabLabel, setTabIcon, EnclosingTabId } from  'lightning/plataformWorkspaceApi';

export default class MyComponent extends OmniscriptBaseMixin(LightningElement){
    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    currentPageRef;
    @wire(EnclosingTabId) enclosingTabId;

    _ns = getNamespaceDotNotation();
    _actionUtilClass;

    @api data;
    @api recordId;

    get recordId() {
        return this.currentPageRef.state.c__ContextId;
    }
    
    async connectedCallback() {
      setTabLabel(this.enclosingTabId, "Summary");
      setTabIcon(this.enclosingTabId, "utility:display_text");
      this._actionUtil = new OmniscriptActionCommonUtil();
      this.data = await callIntegrationProcedure();
    } 

    async callIntegrationProcedure() {
       let input = {recordId: this.recordId};
       let params ={
                      input: JSON.stringify(input),
                      sClassName: `${this._ns}IntegrationProcedureService`,
                      sMethodName: "My_IntegrationProcName",
                      options: "{}",
                    };
       try {
            const response = await 
              this._actionUtil.executeAction(params,null,this,null,null);
            return response;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error, "ERROR");
            return error;
        }
   }

  //Other methods...
}

MyComponent.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>59.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <runtimeNamespace>vlocity_ins</runtimeNamespace>
    <targets>
      <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
      <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
      <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
      <target>lightning__UrlAddressable</target>          
      <target>lightning__Tab</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>


"get" is a special keyword in Javascript, in LWC context, we are using this inside a Class. From your code, you can see you have "@api" recordId and also recordId, 2 declaration. From your code, it seems recordId, is obtained using currentPageRef, in this case you can remove the "@api" recordId from your code.

This particular error means you've declared your recordId with an @api decorator, but you haven't specified a getter and a setter, which when you're trying to set the value, what happens?
The pattern is normally something like:
_recordId;
@api
get recordId() { return this._recordId; }
set recordId(value) {
  this._recordId = value;
}


I just followed the LWC URL Addressable documentation (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_UrlAddressable.htm&language=en_US&release=250&type=5)

If your component is designed for a Record Page and you’re working with the recordId (which Salesforce automatically provides when the component is used on a record page), you don’t need to manually create getters or setters for the recordId.
In such cases, Salesforce will automatically pass the recordId to your LWC component if you have declared it with the @api decorator. You don’t need to define a getter or setter for it. Just use @api recordId, and it will automatically work without further modification.
Here’s how you can simplify the component:
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation'; 
import { getNamespaceDotNotation } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptInternalUtils";
import { OmniscriptActionCommonUtil } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptActionUtils"; 
import { OmniscriptBaseMixin } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptBaseMixin";
import { setTabLabel, setTabIcon, EnclosingTabId } from  'lightning/plataformWorkspaceApi';

export default class MyComponent extends OmniscriptBaseMixin(LightningElement){
    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    currentPageRef;
    @wire(EnclosingTabId) enclosingTabId;

    _ns = getNamespaceDotNotation();
    _actionUtilClass;

    @api data;
    @api recordId; // No need for getter/setter, Salesforce provides this when on a Record Page

    async connectedCallback() {
        setTabLabel(this.enclosingTabId, "Summary");
        setTabIcon(this.enclosingTabId, "utility:display_text");
        this._actionUtil = new OmniscriptActionCommonUtil();
        this.data = await this.callIntegrationProcedure();
    } 

    async callIntegrationProcedure() {
        let input = { recordId: this.recordId };
        let params = {
            input: JSON.stringify(input),
            sClassName: `${this._ns}IntegrationProcedureService`,
            sMethodName: "My_IntegrationProcName",
            options: "{}",
        };
        try {
            const response = await this._actionUtil.executeAction(params, null, this, null, null);
            return response;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error, "ERROR");
            return error;
        }
    }

    // Other methods...
}

Key Points:
•   @api recordId: When your LWC is placed on a record page, Salesforce automatically injects the recordId without needing to manually set it.
•   No need for custom getters/setters for recordId. Just declaring @api recordId; is sufficient.

Since Salesforce takes care of passing the recordId to the component when used in a record context, your component will work seamlessly on a Record Page with the provided recordId. This simplifies your code and avoids the issues you were facing.

Considering that I want to access this LWC for a [custom button and links] (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.defining_custom_links.htm&type=5) ,I will have to use the "get" method because of the Url, right? Or is there a easiest way?
